# How to show only "filled in" fields on an Access report

Tags: ms-access, macros, ms-access-2010

I have created a report for Microsoft access and am trying to add fields to a report only if then have been clicked on our filled out.  The only way I can think of doing this is writing a code or an if-then statement in access.  I have very little experience with writing code and am not sure where to begin.  I'm looking for something like "If a checkbox is selected then add it to the report".

Thank you.

Comment: Do not do this. You will not be able to compile your code. If you want a report with variable fields, build your own using HTML, Word or such like.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to dynamically *add* controls to a report you could include all of the fields on the report and then simply hide the controls that correspond to empty fields. For example, if you have a text field named [SpecialRequirements] and your report contains a bound text box named [txtSpecialRequirements] then in the `On Format` event handler of the report's Detail band you could use

```vbs
Me.txtSpecialRequirements.Visible = (Not IsNull([SpecialRequirements]))
```

which is just a shorthand way of saying

```vbs
If IsNull([SpecialRequirements]) Then
    Me.txtSpecialRequirements.Visible = False
Else
    Me.txtSpecialRequirements.Visible = True
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started - its a basic if structure:

```
If Me!myCheckBox = True Then
     'Write to the report
Else
     'Do something else
End If
```

Also check out the Microsoft Developer Network [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx) for information on the `If...Then..Else` statement

Answer (score 0):

This is really old, but I had the same issue above, but found a easy solution.

- Go to Design view in your "report"
- Make your Yes/No boxes not visible
- Go to the Design tab in your tool bar
- Click on the Controls and click on the Check box and place them over your Yes/No box
- Delete the label it gives with the check box
- Save and look at your report
- Only the YES will appear as a checked box.